# Separando uma String, como faço?

Tags: java, android, string

Tenho uma:

```
String  url = intent://instagram.com/_u/fabiohcnobre/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end
```

Como faço para separar ela de forma que fico  com uma `String link = instagram.com/_u/fabiohcnobre` e um `String package =  com.instagram.android`

Comment: A tag java está correta? Não deveria ser [tag:android] no lugar?

Comment: @Florida não, sei lá se existe alguma API diferente no Android, mas Java está ok e acredito ser suficiente, até pode adicionar outra opciaonlamente.

Comment: @Florida android pode ser programado usando outras linguagens, neste caso, java está correto.

Comment: um `url.replace("intent://", "").split("/#Intent;package=");` não resolveria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como voce conhece o conteudo e as particularidades da sua string, faz assim ó

Separe a string em duas:

```
String [] separada = url.split(";");
```

isso separa a string url em um array de string "*separada*" que vai conter 2 itens, feito isso, ou voce separa cada um desses itens em dois novos usando split e pegando a parte que precisa dele ou voce pode pegar a sub string de cada um desses itens, algo tipo isso:

```
String link = separada[0].split("//")[1];
String pack = separada[1].split("=")[1];
```

ou

```
String link = separada[0].substring(8,separada[0].lenght());
String pack = separada[1].substring(7,separada[1].lenght());
```

acho que é isso, lembrando que o valor 8 do primeiro caso, é o valor que começa a contar a string de 0 até "//', ou seja, pega a string depois delas até o fim e o valor 7 pega a string a contar de 7 até o fim, no caso "=", acredito que o primeiro caso, usando split seja o mais sucinto.

se der algum problema, avisa.

Answer (score 1):

Tente da Seguinte forma:

```
    String  url = "intent://instagram.com/_u/fabiohcnobre/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end";

    // Quebramos os valores onde há ;
    String [] vals = url.split(";");
    // O que nos interessa!!
    String intent  = vals[0];
    String link  = vals[1];

    //Trocamos os valores desnecessários...
    String cleanIntent = intent.replaceAll("#Intent", "").replaceAll("intent://", "");
    //Quebramos o link onde há = e pegamos o segundo item
    String cleanLink = link.split("=")[1];
```